# Late 70's/early 80's LP vinyl book. Other worldly illustrations of people, landscapes, and character sets. I think the music was classical-like

Tags: story-identification, aliens, illustrated-story

I have a memory of an amazing late 70's/early 80's illustrated LP vinyl book. Other worldly illustrations of people, landscapes, and hieroglyphics-like character sets. I think the music was classical-like. It was not Jeff Wayne's *The War of The Worlds*, but would have been a similar size.

I can't find any reference to such a thing anywhere. My siblings and I remember reading it as children during that era. Does anybody have a clue what it was?

Comment: What's an LP book?

Comment: Long Play record, I suspect.

Comment: Yes, LP long player as they would have been called at the time. aka Album, Vinyl, Record. I guess it could be country dependant.

Comment: So was it entirely music to accompany illustrations? Was there narration on the record? Text passages in the book?

Comment: Rick Wakeman's snappily titled "*The Myths and Legends of King Arthur and the Knights of the Round Table*"?

Comment: Fantasy landscapes?  Futuristic?  Noir-esque or utopian?  Was the art packaged inside a LP-like cardboard cover (pamphlet style, like *War of the Worlds*), or was it an actual book with an LP sleeve glued to the inside cover?

Comment: I would say the illustrations were equally as important to the music. Not sure if the illustration reflected the music explicitly though. It was glued to the album so was not removable from what I remember. I would say Utopian, a mixture of modern alien tech but with primitive motif, a bit like Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind.

Comment: it was not Rick Wakeman, sorry.

Comment: [Olias of Sunhillow](https://olias.wordpress.com/) doesn't ring any bells does it?

Comment: Olias of Sunhillow does look really very similar in style. But there were more illustrations, it was like an multi page illustrated book. Very similar, slightly gothic, dripping lines and spikes etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I have Aphantasia and the drawing ability of a 2 year old! if I concentrate hard enough I can see very faint noisey images. I remember there being rose thorns of some sort, possibly someone being spiked by them, with a cut and dripping blood. Sounds a bit dark I realise now!

Comment: Sounds to me like it could be Pentateuch of the Cosmogony - an LP with a book filled with art by Patrick Woodroffe: https://theguitargallery.com/products/patrick-woodroffe-dave-greenslade-the-pentateuch-of-the-cosmogony-double-lp-and-book

Comment: Yes, that's it!  Pentateuch of the Cosmogony. Thank you! I can now calm my mind!

Comment: Some more images of it here: https://vinyllpvault.blogspot.com/2015/02/dave-greenslade-pentateuch-of-cosmogony.html

Comment: @Cassfrank make an answer of that, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was **"[The Pentateuch Of The Cosmogony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pentateuch_of_the_Cosmogony)"** (1979), [as answered by Cassfrank](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/284669/late-70s-early-80s-lp-vinyl-book-other-worldly-illustrations-of-people-lands#comment782477_284669)! Much appreciated.

[Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/master/156967-Patrick-Woodroffe-Dave-Greenslade-The-Pentateuch-Of-The-Cosmogony) says:

> A hardback book and double vinyl album released in 1979, conceived, written and illustrated by Patrick Woodroffe, with music written and performed by Dave Greenslade. The title means, approximately, 'the first five books (pentateuch) of the creation (cosmogony)'.

Further details and images can be found [here](https://vinyllpvault.blogspot.com/2015/02/dave-greenslade-pentateuch-of-cosmogony.html) and [here](https://theguitargallery.com/products/patrick-woodroffe-dave-greenslade-the-pentateuch-of-the-cosmogony-double-lp-and-book).

Comment: Glad that Cassfrank was able to ID this for you. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.